# How to get differences between 2 projected sf objects?

Tags: r

I'm encountering a problem while attempting to use the st_difference function in R's sf package to calculate the differences between two projected spatial objects. this issue seems to occur specifically when the sf objects are projected; if there is no CRS, the function works as expected.

In my actual dataset, I have two Shapefiles (from the NHGIS website): one containing county boundaries represented as polygons, and the other comprising railroad trails represented as linestrings, both within the U.S, both with the same CRS. My aim was to compute the length of trails within each county by performing intersections between the two files. However, upon observation, I noticed that the total trail length decreased in the intersection data compared to the original data. Consequently, I attempted to utilize `st_difference()` to extract all trails without any intersections at all, but the outcome was unsatisfactory.

This led me to examine this function on a simple data and I got this results:

```
if(!"pacman" %in% installed.packages()[ , "Package"]){
  install.packages("pacman")
}
require(pacman)
p_load(dplyr, sf, ggplot2, tidyverse, units)

m = rbind(c(0,0), c(1,0), c(1,1), c(0,1), c(0,0))
p = st_polygon(list(m))
p = st_sfc(p)

m = rbind(c(0.5,0.5), c(0.5,1.5))
l1 = st_linestring(m) %>% st_sfc()

ggplot(p)+
  geom_sf()+
  geom_sf(data = l1, col = "blue")
```

[Linestring and Polygon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W7Ry0.png)

```
inter1 <- st_intersection(l1, p)
diff <- st_difference(l1, inter1)

ggplot(p)+
  geom_sf()+
  geom_sf(data = l1, col = "blue")+
  geom_sf(data = inter1, col = "red", lwd = 2, alpha = 0.25, lty = 1)+
  geom_sf(data = diff, col = "green", lwd = 2, alpha = 0.25, lty = 1)
```

[Intersection in red, Difference in green](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dJHi3.png)

This process functions seamlessly and yields the anticipated results. However, upon projection of these objects, the outcome becomes erroneous:

```
st_crs(p) <- 4326
st_crs(l1) <- 4326

inter1 <- st_intersection(l1, p)
diff <- st_difference(l1, inter1)

ggplot(p)+
  geom_sf()+
  geom_sf(data = l1, col = "blue")+
  geom_sf(data = inter1, col = "red", lwd = 3, alpha = 0.25, lty = 1)+
  geom_sf(data = diff, col = "green", lwd = 2, alpha = 0.5, lty = 5)
```

[Intersection with projected objects](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I07ps.png)

Any insights into why this occurred? Or how can this be rectified for projected data? I attempted to set the CRS to NA in my dataset as a potential solution, but it proved ineffective.

Thanks

I tried to use my data without CRS but it didn't succeed.

Comment: First, are you sure it's really the line/line diff ( `st_difference(l1, inter1)`) you are after and not line/polygon diff  ( `st_difference(l1, p)`) ? Your choice of the coordinate reference system (4326 /  WGS84 ) uses geographic coordinates, i.e. it's unprojected.  Which in turn switches `sf` to use s2 (geometries on a sphere). I don't have a good source to point at, but it seems quite intuitive that most floating point operations would "break" such line/line diff.

Comment: You'd get expected results with your example when switching off  s2, `sf_use_s2(FALSE)` , though for your actual data you may want to use projected CRS instead, UTM for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TD;DR:** This is due to the varying distortions that occur within geographic coordinate systems (GCS) and projected coordinate systems (PCS). Plus, ESRI:102003 makes North America look nice, but it is at the expense of distance accuracy. And let's not forget that the Earth is not a perfect sphere.

**Preamble:** While we do not have access to the data that you are working with, here is a generalised example to show what happens when using different coordinate systems e.g. cartesian coordinates with no CRS, GCS and PCS.

I have created two sets of polygon and line data to illustrate how distortions occur depending on where spatial features are *within a given coordinate system*. To allow a 'like for like' comparison, the coordinates used in this example vary from your example data. That's because your example coordinates fall outside the extent of the CRS your NHGIS data arrive with (ESRI:102003) and therefore would create a non-representative comparison of distortion.

With that in mind, consider the following:

```
library(dplyr)
library(sf)
library(rnaturalearth)
library(lwgeom)
library(units)
library(ggplot2)

# Create sf of US mainland with no CRS (for illustrative purposes only)
us <- ne_countries(scale = "medium", 
                   country = "United States of America",
                   returnclass = "sf") %>%
  st_coordinates() %>%
  data.frame() %>%
  st_as_sf(coords = c("X", "Y")) %>%
  group_by(L2) %>%
  summarise(geometry = st_combine(geometry)) %>% 
  st_cast("POLYGON") %>%
  filter(L2 == 59)

# Create sf objects at southern extent of ESRI:102003
# with cartesian xy 1 x 1 like your example data
m <- rbind(c(-124,25), c(-123,25), c(-123,26), c(-124,26), c(-124,25))
p1 <- st_polygon(list(m)) %>%
  st_sfc() %>%
  st_as_sf()

m <- rbind(c(-123.5,25.5), c(-123.5,26.5))
l1 <- st_linestring(m) %>% 
  st_sfc() %>%
  st_as_sf()

# Create sf objects at northern extent of ESRI:102003
# with cartesian xy 1 x 1 like your example data
m <- rbind(c(-124,48), c(-123,48), c(-123,49), c(-124,49), c(-124,48))
p2 <- st_polygon(list(m)) %>%
  st_sfc() %>%
  st_as_sf()

m <- rbind(c(-123.5,47.5), c(-123.5,48.5))
l2 <- st_linestring(m) %>% 
  st_sfc() %>%
  st_as_sf()

ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = us) +
  geom_sf(data = p1, col = "#490092") +
  geom_sf(data = l1, col = "#920000") +
  geom_sf(data = p2, col = "#004949") +
  geom_sf(data = l2, col = "#006ddb")
```

**Note that p1/l1 are in the south and p2/l2 are in the north:**
[image: result1]

Using the southern sf objects, let's compare the varying distortions  that occur using four different coordinate systems:

```
# Split southern line and calculate line length inside and outside polygon
# with cartesian, GCS, and PCS coordinates
sf_no_crs_1 <- st_split(l1, p1) %>%
  st_collection_extract("LINESTRING") %>%
  mutate(length1 = st_length(x))

sf_gcs_1 <- st_split(l1, p1) %>%
  st_set_crs(4326) %>%
  st_collection_extract("LINESTRING") %>%
  mutate(length1 = st_length(x))

sf_pcs_1 <- st_split(l1, p1) %>%
  st_set_crs(4326) %>%
  st_transform("ESRI:102003") %>%
  st_collection_extract("LINESTRING") %>%
  mutate(length1 = st_length(x))

sf_cec_1 <- st_split(l1, p1) %>%
  st_set_crs(4326) %>%
  st_transform("ESRI:102005") %>%
  st_collection_extract("LINESTRING") %>%
  mutate(length1 = st_length(x))

# Compare length of no CRS, GCS, and PCS split lines
sf_no_crs_1[2,2] - sf_no_crs_1[1,2]
#   length1                       geometry
# 2       0 LINESTRING (0 149.5, -149 0.5)

sf_gcs_1[1,2] - sf_gcs_1[2,2]
#            length1                       geometry
# 1 6.548362e-11 [m] LINESTRING (0 149, -149.5 -...

sf_pcs_1[2,2] - sf_pcs_1[1,2]
#        length1                       geometry
# 2 85.26315 [m] LINESTRING (15651.7 1859848...

sf_cec_1[2,2] - sf_cec_1[1,2]
#        length1                       geometry
# 2 3.829941 [m] LINESTRING (16449.57 173946...
```

As you can see, the line lengths of l1 inside and outside p1 for the cartesian coordinate data are the same, it varies slightly for 4326, and there's a difference of ~85 metres for the ESRI:102003 data. In other words, your original cartesian line length is not treated the same way when a CRS is defined. Note though that using a 'distance-preserving' CRS like ESRI:102005 (USA Contiguous Equidistant Conic) reduces the difference considerably. However, there's *almost always* going to be a difference because no PCS is perfect and the Earth is an ovoid and is not perfectly spherical.

Now let's do the same for the northern sf objects:

```
# Split southern line and calculate line length inside and outside polygon
# with cartesian, GCS, and PCS coordinates
sf_no_crs_2 <- st_split(l2, p2) %>%
  st_collection_extract("LINESTRING") %>%
  mutate(length1 = st_length(x))

sf_gcs_2 <- st_split(l2, p2) %>%
  st_set_crs(4326) %>%
  st_collection_extract("LINESTRING") %>%
  mutate(length1 = st_length(x))

sf_pcs_2 <- st_split(l2, p2) %>%
  st_set_crs(4326) %>%
  st_transform("ESRI:102003") %>%
  st_collection_extract("LINESTRING") %>%
  mutate(length1 = st_length(x))

sf_cec_2 <- st_split(l2, p2) %>%
  st_set_crs(4326) %>%
  st_transform("ESRI:102005") %>%
  st_collection_extract("LINESTRING") %>%
  mutate(length1 = st_length(x))

# Compare length of no CRS, GCS, and PCS split lines
sf_no_crs_2[1,2] - sf_no_crs_2[2,2]
#   length1                     geometry
# 2       0 LINESTRING (0 87.5, -87 0.5)

sf_gcs_2[1,2] - sf_gcs_2[2,2]
#            length1                       geometry
# 1 1.236913e-10 [m] LINESTRING (0 171, -171.5 -...

sf_pcs_2[1,2] - sf_pcs_2[2,2]
#        length1                       geometry
# 1 102.8236 [m] LINESTRING (-15747.84 34405...

sf_cec_2[2,2] - sf_cec_2[1,2]
#        length1                       geometry
# 2 4.862928 [m] LINESTRING (16509.15 334584...
```

The first two result are similar to those of l1/p1, but the difference for the ESRI:102003 data is now ~102 metres. So not only do the lengths differ *within* each area, but the distortion varies *between* each area. Note also that the results for the ESRI:102005 data differ less than for the ESRI:102003, but they *also differ* from the southern data. Again, nothing's perfect and we live on a wonky planet.

In summary, you have to ensure you know what coordinate system *all* of your data are in *prior* to assigning a CRS. This can get complicated particularly in North America given the similarities between WGS84 and NAD83, so you can never assume. Also, if working with distances, you must choose a coordinate system that preserves distance. I have used ESRI:102005 in this example, but this may not be the most appropriate for your actual data. [This link](https://learn.arcgis.com/en/projects/choose-the-right-projection/) is a good starting point for working out which GCS or PCS is right for you.

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert in coordinate systems, but using EPSG:4326 (a system in degrees) seems problematic. User @margusl just wrote some nice comments ( I am a new StackOverflow user, I am restricted on the comments).

By inspecting the intersection, we can see small differences in expected results:

```
st_intersection(l1, p)
inter1
```

With an output of

```
[...]
LINESTRING (0.5 0.5, 0.5 1.000038)
```

A quick search for a [projected coordinate system for the US](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/141588) lead me to
use "ESRI:102003".

Here is the modified full code (I changed the linetype of the green line from lty=5 to lty = 1, the dotted line was confusing ; and other visual details.):

```
if(!"pacman" %in% installed.packages()[ , "Package"]){
  install.packages("pacman")
}
library(tidyverse)
library(sf)
require(pacman)
p_load(dplyr, sf, ggplot2, tidyverse, units)

m = rbind(c(0,0), c(1,0), c(1,1), c(0,1), c(0,0))
p = st_polygon(list(m))
p = st_sfc(p)

m = rbind(c(0.5,0.5), c(0.5,1.5))
l1 = st_linestring(m) %>% st_sfc()

ggplot(p)+
  geom_sf()+
  geom_sf(data = l1, col = "blue")


st_crs(p) <- "ESRI:102003"
st_crs(l1) <- "ESRI:102003"

inter1 <- st_intersection(l1, p)
diff <- st_difference(l1, inter1)

ggplot(p)+
  geom_sf()+
  geom_sf(data = l1, col = "blue")+
  geom_sf(data = inter1, col = "red", lwd = 2, alpha = 0.25, lty = 1)+
  geom_sf(data = diff, col = "green", lwd = 3, alpha = 0.25, lty = 1)
```